# Java connection thread pool AND connectionfactory?

Tags: java, multithreading, factory

I think somebody is confusing their patterns.  I've got one guy telling me to use thread pooling and another telling me to use a ConnectionFactory (granted the second guy is not a software engineer, but a very knowledgeable system architect).  I'm going to use thread pooling, so we can keep the number of connections to a reasonable number of threads.  I've looked all over the internet and I cannot see anywhere where anyone is using both together.  I'm thinking about dumping the ConnectionFactory, because it seems redundant at the very least and I just cannot see why or how to use both.

Just curious to see if somebody more knowledgeable than me has ever seen the two used together and can enlighten me as to why.

Also, each connection has to have its own instance of several other classes and we are using a pub-sub architecture.  I need to make sure that the subscribers are NOT getting a published message that belongs to another connection.  Can I manage that with a ConnectionFactory or do I absolutely need to use a new thread to ensure separation between connection processes?

Just looking for some direction here.

Thank you.

Comment: The two patterns are not contradictory.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen C for your response.  OK.  I just had somebody tell me that most people use one or the other and from my research this appears to be true.  So can you enlighten me further.  I wouldn't have asked the question without doing my research and truly needing some more information on the topic.  Can you please elaborate or point me to some information that is useful to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general **Factory** pattern is *how* to create an object. So `ConnectionFactory` pattern abstracts the way `Conncetion` is created.

Thread pool abstracts the way threads are managed, i.e. the main things are: when they are started, how many of threads are runnable, their scheduling, their stopping - not creation process!

You can use both this patterns. Your *pool* can use *factory* to properly create thread or connection objects.

Comment: Thank you so much ka4eli for clarifying this for me.  I wish I could give you another upvote for telling me how the two can be used together.  :-)